# Beamer: How To Define Colors from Dolphin Theme

Tags: beamer, color

I was trying out different themes, and I accidentally stumbled on a combination of themes whose color combination I very much like (with color theme: Dolphin). I'm using the themes: Berlin, Frankfurt, and Singapore in that order. Obviously, it is not ideal to be using these different themes together, and I really just got lucky by stumbling on this color combination. I would like to be able to define the colors that you see here so that I can use them with just one theme (e.g. Frankfurt), but I couldn't figure out the color names that come with Dolphin. Can someone help me out so I can recreate this *aesthetic* using just one theme? Here is a minimal working example, and a screenshot.

EDITS: (1) I would especially like to know how to do this for Frankfurt as well as Berlin. I like the single line for frame line in Frankfurt, as well as some of the other formatting features it has. But above all, I am interested in figuring out the colors so I can create this scheme myself potentially using a variety of different templates. (2) I'm also hoping to get the TOC header line in white text so it pops more.

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames}]{beamer}
%\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
%\documentclass[10pt, handout]{beamer} %for no pauses

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usetheme{Berlin}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usetheme{Singapore}

\usecolortheme{dolphin}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\inserttocsectionnumber.~\inserttocsection}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
\end{frame}
}

\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=MediumBlue}

\title{Title}

\author{Name}

\institute[University] 
{
  Department \\
  University \\
  }
% - Use the \inst command only if there are several affiliations.
% - Keep it simple, no one is interested in your street address.

\date{DATE}

\begin{document}

%Title Page
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Sample}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Test 
    \item Test 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please use code formatting (by using 4 spaces before each line of your code).

Comment: `\usetheme{Berlin}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{111,110,200}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=myblue}
` should result in somewhat similar colors. The layout of the slides will however look different sine the screenshot in your question was created from a document that does not compile properly due to incompatible beamer themes.

Comment: @leandriis thank you very much. Is there a way to do this starting with Frankfurt? (Also trying to figure out how to change the TOC header line to white font!)

Comment: Probably `\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{111,110,200}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=myblue}` gives the desired output?

Comment: @leandriis Yes, thank you so much! That's very close to what I want. (There are some features I like of from the original hodgepodge, but I'll ask some separate questions about customizing from here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining the `Frankfurt` theme with

```
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{111,110,200}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=myblue}
```

should result in an output with at least somewhat similar colors to the screenshot in the question:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames}]{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{111,110,200}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=myblue}


\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\inserttocsectionnumber.~\inserttocsection}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
\end{frame}
}

\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=MediumBlue}

\title{Title}

\author{Name}

\institute[University] 
{
  Department \\
  University \\
  }
% - Use the \inst command only if there are several affiliations.
% - Keep it simple, no one is interested in your street address.

\date{DATE}

\begin{document}

%Title Page
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\section{section}
\begin{frame}{Sample}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Test 
    \item Test 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```